# How do I simulate Unity3D's grass in LibGDX?

Tags: java, unity-game-engine, libgdx

I am making a game, and would really like to have grass. I have done a lot of research, and have found nothing built into LibGDX to simulate grass.
I am wondering it I could do something like making a plane in my model editor, and just moving the points around, and rotating it to be a little like grass, or is there something that is simpler that I can do to make the grass?
I want my grass looking something like this on [this](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/terrain-Grass.html) website:
[image: Grass example]

Comment: Dude this is the reason people use Unity.  You can spend months working, or you can click one button in Unity  :O  That being said I was able to google **"LibGDX 3D grass" and find many results https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6MGt3n0iEmM  example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VoqXAeHZG_o

Comment: should you be searching "Fur" ?  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0hiojEw2rNA